# What is the difference between nlp.vocab and nlp.vocab.strings?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am learning NLP and I wanted to see the total amount of vocab I have downloaded with spacy.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
nlp2 = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

After importing Spacy and loading both the larger and smaller packages, I checked these:

```
len(nlp.vocab)
```

gives 770,

```
len(nlp2.vocab)
```

gives 761,

```
len(nlp.vocab.strings)
```

gives 83934,

```
len(nlp2.vocab.strings)
```

gives 83914.

How and why do they differ?
How do I check total vocab count of each package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real "vocab" count in spaCy v2.3 or v3. You should mainly think of `nlp.vocab` and `nlp.vocab.strings` as caches where the total count isn't a meaningful value. The `nlp.vocab` `Vocab` is not static and grows as you process texts with the pipeline.

The vocab is a cache of `Lexeme` objects and the `nlp.vocab.strings` `StringStore` is a cache of string hashes. The vocab contains lexemes for tokens that have been seen before in some text that has been processed by the pipeline and the string store contains strings that have been seen before, either as tokens or as annotations (POS labels, lemmas, dependency labels).

The string store is not 100% a cache and may contain strings added during training that haven't been used before in the currently loaded pipeline, but the size of the string store doesn't tell you anything about the pipeline performance.

Answer (score 3):

`len(nlp.vocab)` is the number of cached lexemes, which can therefore vary when you use the model on some words.

`len(nlp.vocab.strings)` maps strings to hash values, and vice versa. It can give you the number of different strings. For the model `en_core_web_md`, this would give you `701800` for example.

If you want to access the words, try:

```
words=[]
for x in nlp.vocab.strings:
    words.append(x)
```